# ESP32-S2 CircuitPython 5x OLED displays (I2C)

Tags: python, esp32, micropython

I want to use the ESP32-S2 with CircuitPython and 5x 0.96inch OLED I2C displays.
It's working fine, but only with 2 displays.

When I assign "i2c3" or more, I'm getting an error. When I keep only "i2c1 and i2c2" or "i2c4 and i2c5" for example, it's working fine again.

But never more than 2 displays at the time.

CODE:

```
import time
import os
import board
import busio
import adafruit_ssd1306
from numbers import *


WIDTH = 128
HEIGHT = 64
CENTER_X = int(WIDTH/2)
CENTER_Y = int(HEIGHT/2)

SDA1 = board.IO41
SCL1 = board.IO42

SDA2 = board.IO39
SCL2 = board.IO40

SDA3 = board.IO37
SCL3 = board.IO38

SDA4 = board.IO35
SCL4 = board.IO36

SDA5 = board.IO33
SCL5 = board.IO34

i2c1 = busio.I2C(SCL1, SDA1)
i2c2 = busio.I2C(SCL2, SDA2)
i2c3 = busio.I2C(SCL3, SDA3)
i2c4 = busio.I2C(SCL4, SDA4)
i2c5 = busio.I2C(SCL5, SDA5)


#if(i2c1.try_lock()):
#    print("i2c1.scan(): " + str(i2c1.scan()))
#    i2c1.unlock()

display1 = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(WIDTH, HEIGHT, i2c1)
display2 = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(WIDTH, HEIGHT, i2c2)
display3 = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(WIDTH, HEIGHT, i2c3)
display4 = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(WIDTH, HEIGHT, i2c4)
display5 = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(WIDTH, HEIGHT, i2c5)

display1.fill(0) # Clear the display
display2.fill(0) # Clear the display
display3.fill(0) # Clear the display
display4.fill(0) # Clear the display
display5.fill(0) # Clear the display

for y, row in enumerate(ZERO):
    for x, c in enumerate(row):
        display5.pixel(x + 0, y + 0, c)
for y, row in enumerate(ONE):
    for x, c in enumerate(row):
        display5.pixel(x + 76, y + 0, c)
display5.show()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 31, in <module>
ValueError: All I2C peripherals are in use
```

How can I fix that?
Thanks

Comment: We have separate Stack Exchange sites for questions about embedded hardware. See [iot.se], f/e.

Comment: There's only 2 i2c busses on the board and they aren't even where you are putting them. I'm surprised it works, at all. The pinout for the S2 shows the i2c on the opposite side of the board.

Comment: There's 4 SPI busses, though. Maybe you could split it up. 2 on I2C and 3 on SPI.

Comment: I2C is a shared bus. Theoretically you can use a single I2C bus with 7-bit addressing to talk to up to 127 slave devices. Unfortunately the SSD1306 supports a choice of only two slave addresses (can be configured using the SA0 pin) so you can use i2c1 and i2c2 to cover a total of 4 displays. The fifth one has to use something else.